# How to iterate over object with css properties and assign to style attribute?

Tags: javascript

this is probably ver simple but I cannot figure it out.

how can I assign the objects values to the buttons style atribute in the for loop below?

```
(function(){
    var parent = {
        color: "orange",
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px"
    }, 
        child = Object.create(parent),
        button = document.querySelector("button");

    button.onclick = function(){
        for (var test in child) {
            button.style.test = // ??
        }
    }

})();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such cases there is a *square bracket notation*:

```
button.style[test] = child[test];
```

**MORE:** http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#squarebracket

Comment: Just beat me to it. ;)

Comment: This is one of those "if only it was jQuery" questions, `button.css(parent)` would do!

Comment: I was just wondering why `hasOwnProperty` isn't needed in this example. Is it because of `Object.create`?

Comment: @Ejay If you're certain of what your objects contain, you rarely need that.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed .. thanks for the fast response!